# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when using Requests in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://getmylevisjordans.co.uk')

print(r.status_code)
```

When running the following code I get the error listed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='getmylevisjordans.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = requests.get('https://getmylevisjordans.co.uk')
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Piers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='getmylevisjordans.co.uk', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

I have tried for hours but cannot seem to get the status code correctly. I am running Python3 on Windows 10.

Comment: SSLLabs reports that the site's SSL certificate chain is incomplete.  That might be why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[***SSL Cert Verification***](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
>   verify to False:

You need to pass extra argument `verify=False` to your request.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 30 2018, 06:42:10)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://getmylevisjordans.co.uk', verify=False)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:857: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
>>> r.status_code
200
>>>
```

Comment: But then the certificate isn't verified. Isn't that a somewhat important part for security.